# How is declare-stylable name linked to the view that uses its attributes?

Tags: android, custom-attributes, android-custom-view, custom-view, declare-styleable

Usually al examples of custom attributes are of the form:

```
<declare-stylable name="MyView">
    <attr name="name" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and its usage:

```
<com.example.test.MyView
    customns:name="Hello"/>
```

So the custom view has the same name as the stylable attributes.

But [in this example (click for full code)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) you see:

```
<declare-styleable name="Options">
    <attr name="titleText" format="string" localization="suggested" />
    <attr name="valueColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

used by:

```
<com.vogella.android.view.compoundview.ColorOptionsView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    custom:titleText="Background color"
    custom:valueColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    />
```

It made me wonder, how is it that `ColorOptionsView` was linked to the attributes defined with name `Options`?

Answer (score 1):

Those options are available as part of the declared `namespace` *custom*, which is included at the top of the `XML` file:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.vogella.android.view.compoundview"
```

**NOTE**

Simply adding this line will not provide support for auto-complete. If that is what your mean by your question, you need to add the schema to your workspace's *XML Catalog*. You can do this in Eclipse by going to `Eclipse -> Preferences`, then `XML -> XML Catalog`. Here, click the `Add...` button. Navigate to the XML Schema file, then select `OK`. If you close and re-open the the XML file, you will now have autocompletion.

---

Finally, when unpacking the attributes used in `ColorOptionsView.java`, the author can specifically look for attributes from this namespace. This is from the same source (commented by me):

```
//grab the declared-styleable resource entries
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Options, 0, 0);
//get the "titleText" entry from this element's attributes
String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.Options_titleText);
//get the "valueColor" attribute. If it does not exists, set the default to holo_blue_light
int valueColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Options_valueColor,
    android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
a.recycle();
```

Comment: That's the code, but how does the connection made in the XML file? Clearly when you edit the XML the auto-complete "knows" which attributes you may write.

Comment: @ilomambo, that is because of the `namespace` declaration, as stated above. If you want to play around this this, remove that line, then close and reopen the `XML` file. You will now notice that the autocomplete has no knowledge of those attributes.

Comment: @ilomambo, I also added some content to my response to address how to hook up XML auto-completion.

Comment: @Phill Just to be clear. You are saying that the namespace declaration directs the XML validator/editor to the java code and the editor scans the code to see which stylable is used in `obtainStyledAttributes` and that's the way it knows that `Options` is used? Do you happen to know where this mechanism is described in the official documentation, or did you deduce it just from the actual behavior?

Comment: @ilomambo, nothing in the XML links to Java code. the XML validator links to the Schema file. My edit about the XML catalog is a generalization however, and may not necessarily be how new `declare-styleable`s work. From what I understand, the Android XML editor validates agains the attr files themselves. This would be my deduction - but makes sense considering that there is no Android layout schema file - only declared-styleables.

Comment: @Phill That's my confusion exactly. I have my own code where I have several stylable groups. If I don't give them the exact custom view name the XML does not show the attributes in auto-complete. So I still don't see where the name `Options` is linked to the custom view in that example. The namespace surely does not contain `Options` and even if you add the file to the XML catalog, how does it know to choose `Options` for that specific view? I sound repetitive and stupid, but I don't see how it is done. I can carry on using it as I do now, but without full undestanding of what is happening.